# Error: Cannot find module 'is-utf8'

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-elixir

Hello guys I'm using elixar package in my project to compile all scss file. I ran the command `npm install` to install all the required dependencies. I ran the `gulp` command but it's throwing me this error.

> Error: Cannot find module 'is-utf8'`.

I have deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran the `npm install` command again and then tried to run `gulp` but it's still throwing this error.

My node version is `6.4.0` and npm version is `3.10.6`.

Please tell me why am I facing this error. I have spent the whole day but I can't figure out why am I facing this error

Comment: It will not fix the actual problem. But you can do `npm install is-utf8`

Comment: @CanVural can i know why am I facing this error.

Comment: @CanVural well you are right about one thing that it did not fix the actual problem. Now it threw me an error for `is-finite` and after I installed that it threw me an error for `number-is-nan`

Comment: You may hit a bug like this one: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1341  There are some workarounds in that page you may try.